# Boxcontainer placement with bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I've been working on a problem that occured recently and i can't find how to solve it. I'm a beginner so forgive me if my problem is really simple.

```
<section class="container">
    <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-8 text-left">
                <div id="filter">
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#" data-filter="*" class="selected"><i class="icon icon-reorder"></i> All Items</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#" data-filter=".cat1"><i class="icon icon-th-large"></i> Exemple</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#" data-filter=".cat2"><i class="icon icon-th-list"></i> Exemple</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#" data-filter=".cat3"><i class="icon icon-th"></i> Exemple</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4 text-right">
                <div id="search">
                <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
                </div>
            </div>
    </div>
</section>

<section class="container">
    <div id="content">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-9">
                <div class="boxportfolio3 item cat2 cat3">
                    <div class="boxcontainer">
                    <img src="../img.jpg" alt="">
                    <div class="roll">
                        <div class="wrapcaption">
                            <a href="projectdetail.html"><i class="icon-link captionicons"></i></a>
                            <a data-gal="prettyPhoto[gallery1]" href="../img.jpg" title="Exemple"><i class="icon-zoom-in captionicons"></i></a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <h1><a href="projectdetail.html">Exemple</a></h1>
                    <p>
                         Exemple
                    </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            <!-- box 2 -->
                <div class="boxportfolio3 item cat1">
                    <div class="boxcontainer">
                        <img src="../img.jpg" alt="">
                        <div class="roll">
                            <div class="wrapcaption">
                                <a href="projectdetail.html"><i class="icon-link captionicons"></i></a>
                                <a data-gal="prettyPhoto[gallery1]" href="../img.jpg" title="Exemple"><i class="icon-zoom-in captionicons"></i></a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <h1><a href="projectdetail.html">Exemple</a></h1>
                        <p>
                             Exemple
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            <!-- box 3 -->
                <div class="boxportfolio3 item cat2 cat3">
                    <div class="boxcontainer">
                        <img src="../img.jpg" alt="">
                        <div class="roll">
                            <div class="wrapcaption">
                                <a href="projectdetail.html"><i class="icon-link captionicons"></i></a>
                                <a data-gal="prettyPhoto[gallery1]" href="../img.jpg" title="Exemple"><i class="icon-zoom-in captionicons"></i></a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <h1><a href="projectdetail.html">Exemple</a></h1>
                        <p>
                             Exemple
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            <!-- box 4 -->
                <div class="boxportfolio3 item cat1">
                    <div class="boxcontainer">
                        <img src="../img.jpg" alt="">
                        <div class="roll">
                            <div class="wrapcaption">
                                <a href="projectdetail.html"><i class="icon-link captionicons"></i></a>
                                <a data-gal="prettyPhoto[gallery1]" href="../img.jpg" title="Exemple"><i class="icon-zoom-in captionicons"></i></a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <h1><a href="projectdetail.html">Exemple</a></h1>
                        <p>
                             Exemple
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-3">
                <div class="text-side">
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec ac velit luctus, pharetra magna eu, auctor purus.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Now since i want my block to be divided in 2 I used a col-md-9 and a col-md-3.

What i get is this : http://image.noelshack.com/fichiers/2015/20/1431873111-resultat.jpg

What i had and what i would like is this : http://image.noelshack.com/fichiers/2015/20/1431873148-attente.jpg

I want my boxcontainer to fill the full space of the col-md-9, but there is this blank space that I cannot fill and I don't know why.

I hope i was clear enough since english is not my native language, and since i'm still a beginner in programming. I'd be happy to hear advices from you.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have defined margins for your "box" items. This means that the width of the div with id="content" is now small to contain your box items plus their margins. try removing any margins

Comment: Hello Tatenda, i tried to remove the margins on the id content but it didn't work, also i tried adding more weight to my col-md-9 that was 75%, i tried with 100% but it didn't work either.

Here is what i have : http://image.noelshack.com/fichiers/2015/20/1431877887-pb.jpg
 I actually want my boxes to fill the whole space so i can have 3 boxes by row, not for my 2 boxes to be centered.

Comment: I think i would understand the problem better and offer some help if i could see the css that affects this section of your code.

Comment: or maybe try to add col-md-4 to all divs with class boxportfolio3